# if/else optimization test results ambigious

Tags: c++, optimization

I am benchmarking three scenarios in my code wherein I want to optimize away an if statement (The value gets set only once at runtime and then checked millions of times) The three approaches I have evaluated are as follows

```
  1. A template bool binded at compile time
  2. A static bool initialized on first call
  3. A bool member variable which gets initialized at construction
```

The results are a bit non intutive i.e. the template version is taking same amount of time but the static member variable approach is faster. Can someone explain why?

Results (consistent on multiple runs)

```
elapsed time: 0.230933 4501s
elapsed time: 0.212918 4501s
elapsed time: 0.230512 4501s
```

example code is here

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

template<bool Condition>
class Test {
public:
    Test() :
        signal_(0.0), condition_(false), max_truncation_(12000.00) {
    }
    ~Test() {
    }

    void CalculateTestingTemplate(double& i);

    void CalculateTestingStatic(double& i);
    void CalculateTestingMemberVariable(double& i);

private:
    double signal_;
    double condition_;

    double max_truncation_;
};

template<bool Condition>
void Test<Condition>::CalculateTestingTemplate(double& i) {
    i++;

    if (Condition) {
        if (fabs(i) > max_truncation_) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (Condition) {
        if (fabs(i) > max_truncation_) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (fabs(i) > max_truncation_) {
        i = 0;
    }
};

template<bool Condition>
void Test<Condition>::CalculateTestingStatic(double& i) {
    i++;
    static bool condition = condition_;
    if (condition) {
        if (fabs(i) > max_truncation_) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (condition) {
        if (fabs(i) > max_truncation_) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (fabs(i) > max_truncation_) {
        i = 0;
    }
};


template<bool Condition>
void Test<Condition>::CalculateTestingMemberVariable(double& i) {
    i++;
    if (condition_) {
        if (fabs(i) > max_truncation_) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (condition_) {
        if (fabs(i) > max_truncation_) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    if (fabs(i) > max_truncation_) {
        i = 0;
    }
};

#endif // TEST_H_
```

and the main function to time it in loop (-O3)

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    Test<false>* object = new Test<false>();
    int iteration = 90000000;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    int i = 0;
    double j = 0;
    for(; i<iteration;i++)
    {
        object->CalculateTestingTemplate(j);
    }
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " " << j << "s\n";

    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for(; i<iteration;i++)
    {
        object->CalculateTestingStatic(j);
    }
    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " " << j << "s\n";


    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for(; i<iteration;i++)
    {
        object->CalculateTestingMemberVariable(j);
    }

    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    elapsed_seconds = end - start;
    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << " " << j << "s\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your assignment to `end` at the end of the timing loop needs to be _before_ your `cout` statements.  Otherwise you're getting too much 'noise' from the output.

Comment: I believe that you profiling results mean nothing. The -O3 probably simply eliminates most of the code anyway. You should look at the resulting assmbly code.

Comment: @elazar, I removed the cout completely and updated the post but the same results (I also have ran it many times (even in loops but very consistent results))

Comment: seems like the first one is useless since you are hardwired at compile time - is that what you want?, if so then just do that. I mean that 1,2,3 are not functionally equivalent

Comment: The question is why is the template one has worse performance than the static solution (I understand what is intended by the code) It is counter intutive

Comment: And my apologies (They are functionally equivalent as well as they do exactly the same computation functionally but the compiler optimization might be different)

Comment: The design of my software will not help me with #ifdef so no I did not do any tests around it

Comment: @Trying_to_get_there it is possible the templated code is allocated away from your test code, so instruction cache misses and TLB misses occur. If you inline the templated version it should eliminate this possibility because the code will be allocated immediately-after the FOR-loops. Also, don't use a static variable, as that is allocated separately. Use a variable which is already allocated within a cacheline you are using (but not a cacheline containing any variables accessed by other threads).

Comment: Thanks @user997112 ... Basically I am looking for the best way to optimize away the branching because I know the value will never change after initialization phase and want the best possible solution for it i.e. have a member boolean variable which is set at initialization and never changes but gets used massively in critical path if(member) { }

Comment: Template it but make sure the templated code is inlined. Why do you perform the same IF statement twice within each test?

Comment: Oh and your template test might be slower than expected because its ran first, therefore encountering cache misses whilst the other tests don't because the template test brought the data in to the cache.

Comment: Yeah @user997112... that sounds like the best possible answer (as the results were counter intutive so i asked for better opinions)

Comment: I'll put it as an answer in case you wish to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your template test might be slower than expected because its ran first, therefore encountering cache misses, whilst the other tests don't encounter cache misses because the template test already brought the data in to the cache.